# Laravel: How to access the table primary key from result

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
Model: User
Primary Key: emp_no (alphanumeric)
Fields: password, remember_token

Model: Employee
Primary Key: emp_no (alphanumeric)
Fields: first_name, last_name
```

Using `$users = Users::with('employee')->get();'`
I could get the list of users with their respective employee record.

I can iterate by

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->emp_no}} //Not working, always returns 0
    {{ $user->password }} //Working
    {{ $user->remember_token }} //Working
    {{ $user->employee->emp_no}} //Not working, always returns 0
    {{ $user->employee->first_name }} //Working
    {{ $user->employee->last_name }} //Working
@endforeach
```

As I commented, both attempt to display the emp_no which is the primary key for both table doesn't work.

Comment: Laravel Eloquent Returns Collection, you have to convert your $users to array. like `$users->toArray();` then return `$users` to view and you can iterate over it

Comment: {{ $user->employee_no }} //Not working because there is not field 'employee_no', use 'emp_no'. similarly {{ $user->employee->employee_no }} //Not working becuase you are using 'employee_no' instead of 'emp_no'. Your tables have 'emp_no' field so use this field.

Comment: @MuhammadInaamMunir its just a typo here sorry

Comment: can you show Model files? i.e. Employee.php and User.php

Comment: model user only has `return $this->hasOne('App\Employee', 'emp_no');` on `employee` function, the model employee is empty, only boilerplate

Comment: when you access a field not present in the object, I'm pretty sure you get null, not 0 which means that the problem might come from code

Comment: its the `$keyType` if I set a new `$primaryKey` from the boilerplate autoincrementing integer, which automatically sets `$keyType` to integer, I need to set it too to string

Comment: its the `$keyType` if I set a new `$primaryKey` from the boilerplate autoincrementing integer, which automatically sets `$keyType` to integer, I need to set it too to string

Answer (score 1):

There's some information lacking, and we chatted for a short while on Laravel's  IRC channel. The issue is *probably* that the model still has `$incrementing = true` and his primary key is a string. The $incrementing property needs to be set to false.

> In addition, Eloquent assumes that the primary key is an incrementing integer value, which means that by default the primary key will be cast to an int automatically. If you wish to use a non-incrementing or a non-numeric primary key you must set the public $incrementing property on your model to false.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Comment: I have found the problem, sorry about my dc on the IRC channel, ISP problem. now the problem is that I didn't set the `$keyType` to string, thats why whenever I try to access the emp_no, it always gives 0 rather than the supposed alphanumeric value